# Use of parallels in java shows no increase in performance

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I recently embarked on a project to simulate a collection of stellar bodies with the use of LWJGL. The solution required many loop iterations per frame to accomplish. The program calculates the forces exerted on each body by every other body. I did not wish to implement any form of limitations, such as tree algorithms. The program itself is able to simulate 800 bodies of random mass (between 1 and 50) at around 15 fps. Here is the original code for calculating, then updating the position of each body.

```
public void updateAllBodies() {
    for (Body b : bodies) {
        for (Body c : bodies) {
            if (b != c) {
                double[] force = b.getForceFromBody(c, G);
                b.velocity[0] += force[0];
                b.velocity[1] += force[1];
                b.velocity[2] += force[2];
                b.updatePosition();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Recently I came across the subject of parallels and streams. Seeing that my original code used only one thread, I thought I might be able to improve the performance by converting the array to a stream, and executing it with the use of

```
.parallelStream()
```

I don't know much about multi-threading and parallelism, but here is the resulting code that I came up with.

```
public void updateAllBodies() {
    Arrays.asList(bodies).parallelStream().forEach(i -> {
        for(Body b: bodies){
        if (i != b){
            double[] force = i.getForceFromBody(b, G);
            i.velocity[0] += force[0];
            i.velocity[1] += force[1];
            i.velocity[2] += force[2];
            i.updatePosition();
        }
       }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, when executed, this new code resulted in the same 15 fps as the old one. I was able to confirm that there were 3 concurrent threads running with

```
Thread.currentThread().getName();
```

At this point, I have no idea as to what the cause could be. lowering the number of bodies does show a drastic increase in frame rate. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does your PC have more than 2 cpu cores? also, its a bit strange to see you are trying to change values in bodies as you are iterating through it, not sure if the parallelStream() will be affected

Comment: Thank you for your response. I suppose I should store the changes until after the loops, and will do so. The program is running on a laptop with 2 physical cores, and 4 threads.

Comment: multithreading does not help unless you have spare cores, since the additional threads will instead cause overheads context switching on the 2 physical cores you have. The same prog might work much faster on a 4 core (physical) machine

Comment: Thank you. I must have misunderstood how multithreading actually works, seeing how other different applications seem to benifit. I will try the program on another computer, seeing how it should have been the first thing I did.

Comment: I have tested the application on a quad core machine. Unfortunately, its processor is about 2 years older than my dual core, has about 3/5th the processing power, and the frame rate seems to fit that trend exactly. Despite this, I did see utilization across all four cores. With this information, i'm reasonably sure the two cores of my laptop was the issue.

Comment: *"I don't know much about multi-threading and parallelism.... At this point, I have no idea as to what the cause could be."* ... So why are you, then, wasting bandwidth attempting to raise flags and alarms about a subject on which you are unable to speak authoritatively?  Parallelism is not magic.  Like everything else it comes with costs and benefits.  Being ignorant of the costs doesn't mean that the whole system must be broken ... only that you don't know how it works and when it is best to use it.

Comment: I did not intend for the message to come across that way. What i meant to say was that my current understanding was wrong, and needed improvement. That's why I decided to post here in hopes someone with a better understanding of the subject would be able to provide some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant seem to find a way to mark a comment as the answer to a post, so I will state that the best answer was given by `softwarenwebie7331`.